# Django debug False prevents access to files saved in media folder

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, heroku, whitenoise

I have a model that takes a File Field which is uploaded in Django admin. I noticed that the files save in the proper folder. But when Debug is set to False, I cannot access the file from the admin area or from the front end user interface. I get an error message that says "The resource could not be found on the server."

The app is hosted on Heroku and does the same thing in localhost and live. I read in another post that Whitenoise would work with Heroku but it hasn't resolved the issue. Could someone please point me in the right direction to a fix? The relevant files are below.

**Update:** Adding urls.py

#### urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from .views import DatasetListView
from django.conf import settings
import pages.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('downloads/', views.DatasetListView.as_view(), name='downloads'), # where users download the files
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

#### models.py

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.db import models

class DataSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    file_size = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    data_file = models.FileField(upload_to='delivery/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### settings.py

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = Redacted

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False  
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # third-party apps
    'anymail',

    # project apps
    'pages',
    'users',
    'allauth', 
    'allauth.account', 
    'allauth.socialaccount', 
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = Redacted

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Redacted',
        'USER': 'Redacted',
        'PASSWORD': 'Redacted',
        'HOST': '/Redacted',
        'PORT': 'Redacted'
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'mysite.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

# Configure Django App for Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you also please add `urls.py`, so that we can see those actual URL resolvings to understand the situation better

Comment: Sure, I've just updated the question with the urls.py code

Comment: Actually, `urls.py` showed the problem. So, django does not provide file serving on production and it is a problem when you deploy to PaaS like Heroku. Why it is working on `debug=True`, because with that settings it provides kind of static file serving for the only purpose of development. I really recommend you to read WhiteNoise for serving static files from other cloud servers.

Comment: Ok thanks I thought Whitenoise was enough. I'll look at a CDN.